# How can i compress image size with multer on upload?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

How can i make compression on image size on upload, i will have a lot of files in my S3 bucket so i need this.

How can i transofrm this code do to that ?

```
app.post('/api/v1/upload', upload.array('image', 1), (req, res) => {
  res.send({ image: req.file });
});


aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: 'us-east-1' //E.g us-east-1
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Invalid file type, only JPEG and PNG is allowed!'), false);
  }
};


const upload = multer({
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    acl: 'public-read',
    s3,
    bucket: 'oldst123',
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      req.file = file.originalname;
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: If you are storing the file directly into the bucket, then there is nothing you can do, you need to store the file in local file system, run the file compression algorithm, and then write it into aws bucket, and after that delete the image from your local file system(if you dont need it).